# how to run a script with tqdm in background

Tags: python, tqdm

Here is a simple script that uses the `tqdm` progress bar:

```
from tqdm import tqdm
from time import sleep

for i in tqdm(range(10000)):
  sleep(1)
```

Sometimes I want to let it run on my server and exit. Naturally, in those cases I'm not really interested in seeing the progress bar. I do this:

```
$ python mytest.py &
$ disown
$ exit
```

But once I exit, the process stops. Why does it happen and what to do about it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the answer might be mentioned [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/148698/114417).

Calling `disown` does *not* completely disconnect the process from the terminal. Since `sys.stdin`, `sys.stout` and `sys.stderr` are inherited from the shell, if the terminal is destroyed, the script will fail as soon as it tries to print to standard error, which `tqdm` attempts to do.

I don't know if you are running a subshell or if the `exit` command destroys the terminal. If the latter is true, that might explain why the process terminates. You could perhaps try to [redirect](https://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/how-to-redirect-output-and-errors-to-devnull/) all terminal output to `/dev/null` and see if that helps?